# In regex you use $ to check if something is at the end how would i do that in the haskell version if regex?

Tags: regex, haskell

Checking if the words are just "big" or "small"

^big$|^small$|

The ^ seems to work fine but I'm struggling with implementing the $

Comment: Can you specify which library you're using? There's no standard regex library, and they're a rather uncommon tool to use in Haskell.

Comment: ``(`elem` ["big", "small"])`` This isn't something you would use regular expressions for in virtually any language.

Comment: `^big$|^small$`, remove the last `|`